# Get version of major libraries/modules included in webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

Is there any way to get what all libraries/script/modules included in webpack bundle from developer's console(you can consider a website is already running and you don't have access to its codebase) and also know there npm module version ?

Answer (score 3):

Webpack does not keep the module versions, which is normal because you would not need it in production.

However, you can try to get the dependencies by parsing the vendor file and looking at all the `imports` and `require` statements.

Answer (score 0):

As @Seblor said. Step by step would be to open `index.html` file using Chrome Developer tools or similar.

There you will probably find code like:

```
<script src="/Scripts/dist/client.bundle.12345.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/dist/LICENSE.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="https://12345.cloudfront.net/dist/js/main-react-12345.js"></script>
<script src="https://12345.cloudfront.net/dist/js/vendor-12345.js"></script>
```

Navigate to either `LICENSE.js` or `vendor-12345.js`. `LICENSE.js` is often easier to read than vendor file but both work.

I usually search for `@license`, `@author`, `@copyright` and `Copyright` to see what libraries are used.